# Loading OpenCL kernels from bitcode in the correct architecture

Tags: xcode, macos, opencl, gpgpu

I'm using Xcode (version 5.3) to compile OpenCL kernels to bitcode, as explained in WWDC 2013 session 508.

Xcode generates 4 different files, each with a different extension according to the architecture for which it has been targeted for.

The extensions are: cl.gpu_32.bc , cl.gpu_64.bc , cl.x84_64.bc, cl.i386.bc

In session 508, they only load a single file (The one with the cl.gpu_32.bc extension and use it).

Is it possible to generate a single cl_program that support all devices associated with the context?

How do I know which architecture to use for each of the available devices?

A sample code that reads all files and generate a single cl_program would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides sample code that covers loading platform-specific bitcode:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenCLOfflineCompilation/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011196

From the description:

> This sample demonstrates how developers can utilize the OpenCL offline
>   compiler to transform their human-readable OpenCL source files into
>   shippable bitcode. It includes an example Makefile that demonstrates
>   how to invoke the compiler, and a self-contained OpenCL program that
>   shows how to build a program from the generated bitcode. The sample
>   covers the case of using bitcode on 64 and 32 bit CPU devices, as well
>   as 32 bit GPU devices.

The [readme](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenCLOfflineCompilation/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011196-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_3) covers the CLI arguments and the single-file C program contains lots of explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Seems from Apple Sample Code (referenced by weichsel), that all is needed is to get CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS and CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU using clGetDeviceInfo to distinguish between all possible different architectures.